# Shorter / better way to simulate dropWhile in polars

Tags: python, python-polars

Say I have this:

```
>>> df = polars.DataFrame(dict(j=[1,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,2], k=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]))
>>> df
shape: (9, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ j   ┆ k   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 1   │
│ 1   ┆ 2   │
│ 1   ┆ 3   │
│ 2   ┆ 4   │
│ 1   ┆ 5   │
│ 2   ┆ 6   │
│ 1   ┆ 7   │
│ 2   ┆ 8   │
│ 2   ┆ 9   │
└─────┴─────┘
```

Is there a shorter / better way to simulate `dropWhile` (i.e. remove all the rows at the top of the DataFrame that satisfy a certain condition) than this (which removes all initial rows that have `j == 1`):

```
>>> df.slice(df.with_row_count().filter(polars.col('j') != 1).select('row_nr').head(1).item())
shape: (6, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ j   ┆ k   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 2   ┆ 4   │
│ 1   ┆ 5   │
│ 2   ┆ 6   │
│ 1   ┆ 7   │
│ 2   ┆ 8   │
│ 2   ┆ 9   │
└─────┴─────┘
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `.cumsum` the result of the comparison:

```
df.with_columns(cumsum = (pl.col("j") != 1).cumsum())
```

```
shape: (9, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬────────┐
│ j   ┆ k   ┆ cumsum │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---    │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ u32    │
╞═════╪═════╪════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 0      │
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 0      │
│ 1   ┆ 3   ┆ 0      │
│ 2   ┆ 4   ┆ 1      │
│ 1   ┆ 5   ┆ 1      │
│ 2   ┆ 6   ┆ 2      │
│ 1   ┆ 7   ┆ 2      │
│ 2   ┆ 8   ┆ 3      │
│ 2   ┆ 9   ┆ 4      │
└─────┴─────┴────────┘
```

Which you can `.filter`

```
df.filter((pl.col("j") != 1).cumsum() != 0)
```

```
shape: (6, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ j   ┆ k   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 2   ┆ 4   │
│ 1   ┆ 5   │
│ 2   ┆ 6   │
│ 1   ┆ 7   │
│ 2   ┆ 8   │
│ 2   ┆ 9   │
└─────┴─────┘
```

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to remove the top `n` rows where `j==1` then you can get that with

```
df.with_row_count('i').filter(pl.col('j')!=1).select(pl.col('i').min())
```

and then you can use square brackets to subset to that

```
df[df.with_row_count('i').filter(pl.col('j')!=1).select(pl.col('i').min()).item():]

shape: (6, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ j   ┆ k   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 2   ┆ 4   │
│ 1   ┆ 5   │
│ 2   ┆ 6   │
│ 1   ┆ 7   │
│ 2   ┆ 8   │
│ 2   ┆ 9   │
└─────┴─────┘
```

Without square bracket self reference, you could do...

```
df.filter(~((pl.col('j')==1).cumsum()==(pl.col('j').cumcount()+1)))
```